# Does Jetpack Compose offer a Material AutoComplete TextView replacement?

Tags: android, material-components-android, android-jetpack-compose

In the process of migrating my app to Jetpack compose, I've come to a part of my app where a TextField needs autocompletion functionality.

However, as of version 1.0.0-alpha05, I couldn't find any functionality to achieve this using the Compose API. The closest thing I've found is the `DropdownMenu` and `DropdownMenuItem` composeables, but it seems like it would be a lot of manual plumbing required to create an autocomplete menu out of these.

The obvious thing to do is just wait for future updates to Jetpack Compose, of course. But I'm wondering, has anyone who encountered a this issue in their migrations found a solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67111020/exposed-drop-down-menu-for-jetpack-compose/67111599#67111599

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of compose 1.1.0-alpha06, Compose Material now offers an `ExposedDropdownMenu` composable, API [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#ExposedDropdownMenuBox(kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function1)), which can be used to implement a dropdown menu which facilitates the autocompletion process. The actual autocompletion logic has to be implemented yourself.

The API docs give the following usage example, for an editable field:

```
val options = listOf("Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4", "Option 5")
var exp by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
var selectedOption by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
ExposedDropdownMenuBox(expanded = exp, onExpandedChange = { exp = !exp }) {
    TextField(
        value = selectedOption,
        onValueChange = { selectedOption = it },
        label = { Text("Label") },
        trailingIcon = {
            ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = exp)
        },
        colors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.textFieldColors()
    )
    // filter options based on text field value (i.e. crude autocomplete)
    val filterOpts = options.filter { it.contains(selectedOption, ignoreCase = true) }
    if (filterOpts.isNotEmpty()) {
        ExposedDropdownMenu(expanded = exp, onDismissRequest = { exp = false }) {
            filterOpts.forEach { option ->
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    onClick = {
                        selectedOption = option
                        exp = false
                    }
                ) {
                    Text(text = option)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the sample link. the only thing that doesn't work is the filtering. the pop up menu always dismisses weirdly. anyone else?

Comment: @c_idle Maybe it's due to newer Compose (using v1.4.3) or Material3, but I had to adjust the `DropdownMenuItem` to have the `Text()` composable declared in the constructor, along with the `onclick()`, rather than as a Composable in the body of the `DropdownMenuItem` (using the last Composable parameter thing, forget the name for that). Also you need to specify a `Modifier` on the `TextField` calling the `.menuAchor()` function otherwise you'll get an exception regarding Focusable. It works except I can only type a single character in the textfield if that char exists in the dropdown options

Comment: Working with v1.5.0-beta2, `ExposedDropdownMenu#onDismissRequest` is called even when `TextField` is focused and during typing.

Answer (score 10):

No at least till v1.0.2

so I implemented a nice working one in compose available in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/amparhizgar/e377e575e734ca0efe4e0c0afee36099)

I also put it here:

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.focus.onFocusChanged
import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextRange
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.TextFieldValue
import androidx.compose.ui.window.PopupProperties


@Composable
fun TextFieldWithDropdown(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    value: TextFieldValue,
    setValue: (TextFieldValue) -> Unit,
    onDismissRequest: () -> Unit,
    dropDownExpanded: Boolean,
    list: List<String>,
    label: String = ""
) {
    Box(modifier) {
        TextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .onFocusChanged { focusState ->
                    if (!focusState.isFocused)
                        onDismissRequest()
                },
            value = value,
            onValueChange = setValue,
            label = { Text(label) },
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors()
        )
        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = dropDownExpanded,
            properties = PopupProperties(
                focusable = false,
                dismissOnBackPress = true,
                dismissOnClickOutside = true
            ),
            onDismissRequest = onDismissRequest
        ) {
            list.forEach { text ->
                DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                    setValue(
                        TextFieldValue(
                            text,
                            TextRange(text.length)
                        )
                    )
                }) {
                    Text(text = text)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**How to use it**

```
val all = listOf("aaa", "baa", "aab", "abb", "bab")

val dropDownOptions = mutableStateOf(listOf<String>())
val textFieldValue = mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue())
val dropDownExpanded = mutableStateOf(false)
fun onDropdownDismissRequest() {
    dropDownExpanded.value = false
}

fun onValueChanged(value: TextFieldValue) {
    dropDownExpanded.value = true
    textFieldValue.value = value
    dropDownOptions.value = all.filter { it.startsWith(value.text) && it != value.text }.take(3)
}

@Composable
fun TextFieldWithDropdownUsage() {
    TextFieldWithDropdown(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        value = textFieldValue.value,
        setValue = ::onValueChanged,
        onDismissRequest = ::onDropdownDismissRequest,
        dropDownExpanded = dropDownExpanded.value,
        list = dropDownOptions.value,
        label = "Label"
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this code that I made using XML and using that layout inside compose
using `AndroidView`. We can use this solution until it is included by default in compose.

You can customize it and style it as you want. I have personally tried it in my project and it works fine

```xml
<!-- text_input_field.xml -->
<!-- You can style your textfield here in XML with styles -->
<!-- this file should be in res/layout -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Label"
        android:inputType="none" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

```
// TextFieldWithDropDown.kt
// TextField with dropdown was not included by default in jetpack compose (1.0.2) and less

@Composable
fun TextFieldWithDropDown(
    items: List<String>,
    selectedValue: String?,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onSelect: (Int) -> Unit
) {
    AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->
            val textInputLayout = TextInputLayout
                .inflate(context, R.layout.text_input_field, null) as TextInputLayout
            
            // If you need to use different styled layout for light and dark themes
            // you can create two different xml layouts one for light and another one for dark
            // and inflate the one you need here.

            val autoCompleteTextView = textInputLayout.editText as? AutoCompleteTextView
            val adapter = ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items)
            autoCompleteTextView?.setAdapter(adapter)
            autoCompleteTextView?.setText(selectedValue, false)
            autoCompleteTextView?.setOnItemClickListener { _, _, index, _ -> onSelect(index) }
            textInputLayout
        },
        update = { textInputLayout ->
            // This block will be called when recomposition happens
            val autoCompleteTextView = textInputLayout.editText as? AutoCompleteTextView
            val adapter = ArrayAdapter(textInputLayout.context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items)
            autoCompleteTextView?.setAdapter(adapter)
            autoCompleteTextView?.setText(selectedValue, false)
        },
        modifier = modifier
    )
}
```

```
// MainActivity.kt
// It's important to use AppCompatActivity instead of ComponentActivity to get the material
// look on our XML based textfield

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        
        setContent {
            Column {
                TextFieldWithDropDown(
                    items = listOf("One", "Two", "Three"),
                    selectedValue = "Two",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(16.dp)
                ) {
                    // You can also set the value to a state
                    index -> println("$index was selected")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29802524)

Comment: Hey thanks for letting me know since I am new here I didn't think of that now I have included the code in the answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

after so many research I have created perfect Autocomplete that's works like AutoCompleteView

just copy paste and use on your project.

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.DropdownMenuItem
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.ExposedDropdownMenuBox
import androidx.compose.material3.ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.TextField
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun DropDown(
    items: List<String>,
    onItemSelected: (String) -> Unit,
    selectedItem: String,
    label: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var listItems by remember(items, selectedItem) {
        mutableStateOf(
            if (selectedItem.isNotEmpty()) {
                items.filter { x -> x.startsWith(selectedItem.lowercase(), ignoreCase = true) }
            } else {
                items.toList()
            }
        )
    }
    var selectedText by remember(selectedItem) { mutableStateOf(selectedItem) }
    
    LaunchedEffect(selectedItem){
        selectedText = selectedItem
    }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 2.dp)
    ) {
        ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
            expanded = expanded,
            onExpandedChange = {
                expanded = !expanded
            },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            TextField(
                value = selectedText,
                label = { Text(label) },
                onValueChange = {
                    if (!expanded) {
                        expanded = true
                    }
                    selectedText = it
                    listItems = if (it.isNotEmpty()) {
                        items.filter { x -> x.startsWith(it.lowercase(), ignoreCase = true) }
                    } else {
                        items.toList()
                    }
                },
                trailingIcon = { ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = expanded) },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .menuAnchor()
            )

            ExposedDropdownMenu(
                expanded = expanded,
                onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }
            ) {
                if (listItems.isEmpty()) {
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                        text = { Text(text = "No items found") },
                        onClick = {
                            expanded = false
                        }
                    )
                } else {
                    listItems.forEach { item ->
                        DropdownMenuItem(
                            text = { Text(text = item) },
                            onClick = {
                                selectedText = item
                                expanded = false
                                onItemSelected(item)
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

As you said, there is no such component yet. You have two options: create your own custom using `DropDownMenu` and `BaseTextField` or using hybrid xml-autocomplete and compose screen through `androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView`

Comment: Have you made a custom composable like you described? It would be nice to see an example of what a finished solution looks like.

Comment: I'm sorry I didnt implement that but I know a lib that you could use as AutoCompleteText (you will need to implement a couple of things but this lib will save a lot of your time).
Check it out : https://github.com/skydoves/Orchestra#spinner