# Cannot make ExposedDropdownMenu same width as OutlinedTextField

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I faced the following problem - items of the dropdown are not the same width as OutlinedTextField

[image]

Looked for the solution - found the following:

1. Add the variable to keep `textField` width:

   ```
   var textFieldSize by remember { mutableStateOf(Size.Zero) }
   ```
2. Set the value in the `onGloballyPositioned` of `TextField`

   ```
   onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
       textFieldSize = coordinates.size.toSize()
   }
   ```
3. Read the value in `ExposedDropdownMenu`

   ```
   ExposedDropdownMenu(
       expanded = expanded,
       onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
       modifier = Modifier
           .background(Color.White)
           .width(with(LocalDensity.current) { textFieldSize.width.toDp() })
   )
   ```

The problem is that it works fine with `DropdownMenu`, but doesn't work with `ExposedDropdownMenu`. What's the problem?

Here's the full code:

```
var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val genderList by remember { mutableStateOf(listOf("Male", "Female")) }
var textFieldSize by remember { mutableStateOf(Size.Zero) }

val icon = if (expanded)
    Icons.Filled.ArrowDropUp
else
    Icons.Filled.ArrowDropDown

ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
    modifier = modifier
        .clickable(onClick = { expanded = true }),
    expanded = expanded,
    onExpandedChange = { expanded = !expanded }
) {
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = "",
        onValueChange = {},
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                textFieldSize = coordinates.size.toSize()
            },
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
            backgroundColor = BorderColor,
            unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
            focusedIndicatorColor = BrandColor,
            focusedLabelColor = BrandColor,
        ),
        leadingIcon = {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_complete_registration_sex),
                contentDescription = null
            )
        },
        trailingIcon = { Icon(icon, null) },
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(Dimen.Dimen14),
        label = {
            Text(
                "Choose Gender",
                style = PoppinsNormalStyle14
            )
        },
        readOnly = true
    )

    ExposedDropdownMenu(
        expanded = expanded,
        onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.White)
            .width(with(LocalDensity.current) { textFieldSize.width.toDp() })
    ) {
        genderList.forEach {
            DropdownMenuItem(
                onClick = { expanded = false },
            ) {
                Text(it, style = PoppinsNormalStyle12Gray2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`ExposedDropdownMenuBox` is built to calculate width for you so you don't have to use all this `onGloballyPositioned` related logic.

The fact that it doesn't work is a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/205589613).

Until it's fixed it's recommended to use `DropdownMenu` with `Modifier.exposedDropdownSize()`(this modifier will apply the width calculated by `ExposedDropdownMenuBox`) instead of `ExposedDropdownMenu`:

```
DropdownMenu(
    expanded = expanded,
    onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.White)
        .exposedDropdownSize()
) {
    genderList.forEach {
        DropdownMenuItem(
            onClick = { expanded = false },
        ) {
            Text(it, style = PoppinsNormalStyle12Gray2)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is exactly like you explained, known bug and changing to DropdownMenu is a valid workaround.

Comment: noted, this makes sense, I tried any different part from simple `fillMaxWidth` to `globalPosition`, turns out no clue why still not happening. this solve my issue, thanks!