# How to make EditText act like a spinner in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-jetpack-compose, android-spinner

I'm trying to get an EditText view to show a spinner when clicked then display the selection or at least something like the underlined spinner but with a leading and trailing icon.

*PS: The EditText view would look like a proper EditText view with hints, icons and all*

Is there any way to do this in Compose please?

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67111599/2016562)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ExposedDropdownMenu` is what you looking for i assume

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
fun ExposedSelectionMenu(
    title: String,
    index: Int,
    options: List<String>,
    onSelected: (Int) -> Unit
) {

    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var selectedOptionText by remember { mutableStateOf(options[index]) }

    ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(vertical = 4.dp),
        expanded = expanded,
        onExpandedChange = {
            expanded = !expanded
        }
    ) {
        TextField(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            readOnly = true,
            value = selectedOptionText,
            onValueChange = { },
            label = { Text(title) },
            trailingIcon = {
                ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(
                    expanded = expanded
                )
            },
            colors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.textFieldColors(
                backgroundColor = Color.White,
                focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                disabledIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
            )
        )
        ExposedDropdownMenu(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = {
                expanded = false

            }
        ) {
            options.forEachIndexed { index: Int, selectionOption: String ->
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    onClick = {
                        selectedOptionText = selectionOption
                        expanded = false
                        onSelected(index)
                    }
                ) {
                    Text(text = selectionOption)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```