# Jetpack Compose ExposedDropdownMenu not showing up when pressed

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield, android-jetpack-compose-material3, android-compose-exposeddropdown

I'm working on a Jetpack Compose (1.3.0-beta03) and Material3 (1.0.0-beta03) app.

I'd like to show the user a simple dropdown with different languages, and the following code isn't very different from what you'll find online:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun Settings() {
    val languages = listOf("it", "en", "de", "ro", "fr", "es")

    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var selectedOptionText by remember { mutableStateOf("ro") }

    ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
        expanded = expanded,
        onExpandedChange = { expanded = !expanded },
    ) {
        TextField(
            readOnly = true,
            value = selectedOptionText,
            onValueChange = {},
            label = { Text(stringResource(R.string.default_reading_language)) },
            trailingIcon = { ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = expanded) },
            colors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.textFieldColors(),
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        )
        ExposedDropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }
        ) {
            languages.forEach {
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    text = { Text(it) },
                    onClick = {
                        selectedOptionText = it
                        expanded = false
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running on the emulator show the Textfield correctly, but if I click on it, does not show the dropdown. It also set the correct option ("ro"), as expected.

No clue on how to fix this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67111020/exposed-drop-down-menu-for-jetpack-compose

Comment: @android I've already checked out that. The accepted answer is almost identical to my code. There is something I should point my attention to?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

With M2 your code works well.

With M3 you have to pass the **`menuAnchor`** modifier to the `TextField` (it was introduced with [`material3 1.0.0-beta03`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3#1.0.0-beta03)):

```
ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
    modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
    expanded = expanded,
    onExpandedChange = { expanded = !expanded },
) {
   TextField(
        //...
        modifier = Modifier.menuAnchor()
    )
    ExposedDropdownMenu(
        /* .. */
    ) { /*..  */ }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It works, perfectly. Grazie Gabriele