# Search with DropDownItem in OutlineTextField not overlaying over content

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield, android-jetpack-compose-ui, android-compose-exposeddropdown

I am trying to achieve search functionality in compose using `DropDownItem` but it is displaying below `OutlineTextField`. All the available option is not displaying over the content like DropDown menu.

**Effort 1:** Tried using `DropDownMenu` but in that case, the text field was not in the correct location and bounced over the screen depending on the list of options. (Working as a popUp)

**Effort 2:** I can not use `ExposedDropDownMenuBox` as it will require M3 and I am currently using M2 in my project and we can not convert the whole project to M3 for this.

Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my `SearchField` composable look like

```
    @Composable
fun SearchField(
    optionList: List<Address>,
    label: String,
    searchText: String,
    isSearching: Boolean,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
) {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    var textfieldSize by remember { mutableStateOf(Size.Zero) }

    var selectedText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    val focusRequester = FocusRequester()

//    DropdownMenu(
//        modifier = Modifier
//            .fillMaxWidth()
//            .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
//                //This value is used to assign to the DropDown the same width
//                textfieldSize = coordinates.size.toSize()
//            },
//        expanded = true,
////            properties = PopupProperties(usePlatformDefaultWidth = true),
//        onDismissRequest = {
//        }
//    ) {

        OutlinedTextField(
            value = searchText,
            enabled = true,
            onValueChange = {
                selectedText = it
                onValueChange(it)
            },

            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                    //This value is used to assign to the DropDown the same width
                    textfieldSize = coordinates.size.toSize()
                },
            label = { Text(label) },
        )

        if (expanded) {
            if (isSearching) {
                CircularProgressIndicator()
            }

            optionList.forEach { address ->
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    onClick = {
                        println("Selected Address : ${address.addressLine1}")
                        selectedText = address.addressLine1
                        expanded = !expanded
                    }
                ) {
                    Text(text = address.addressLine1)
                }
            }
        }

//    }

}
```

Here's what it look like right now

[image]

Here is the try with `Box`

```
        Box {
        // Address 1
        EditableRow(
//            modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester),
            value = state.address1.value.toString(),
            onValueChange = {
                state.address1.value = it
                isSearchExpanded = true
                customerDetailsViewModel.onSearchText(it)
            },
            error = state.address1.error.orEmpty(),
            hintText = stringResource(id = R.string.address),
            enabled = state.isAddressEditable,
            trailingIcon = {
                if (isTrailingVisible.value && state.isAddressEditable) {
                    CloseIcon(modifier = Modifier.clickable { isSearchExpanded = !isSearchExpanded }) {
                        state.address1.value = ""
                        focusRequester.requestFocus()
                    }
                }
            },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
                imeAction = ImeAction.Done,
            ),
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = {
                focusManager.clearFocus()
            })
        )

        DropdownMenu(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
            expanded = isSearchExpanded, onDismissRequest = { }) {

            searchList.forEach { address ->
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    onClick = {
                        state.address1.value = address.addressLine1
//                        selectedText = address.addressLine1
                        isSearchExpanded = !isSearchExpanded
                        focusManager.clearFocus()
                    }
                ) {
                    Text(text = address.addressLine1)
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `ExposedDropDownMenuBox` exists also for [M2](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/ExposedDropdownMenuBoxScope) and it is the best option.

In your solution you have to add the `DropdownMenu` if you want to display the menu in a separate window, on top of other content.

Something like:

```
    Box() {
        OutlinedTextField(
           //...
        )


        DropdownMenu(
            //...
        ) {

            items.forEach { label ->
                DropdownMenuItem(
                   //....
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for response. @Gabriele I am using compose version 1.0.0 and I believe it doesn’t exist in that version. I will try your solution and let you know. 

I have tried using DropDownMenu but I haven’t tried with Box layout. 


Second I tried adding DropDownMenu but my co

Comment: @ArpitPatel it would be better to update from 1.0.0 the 1.3.0. The 1.0.0 is very old.

Comment: Tried using this way but can not able to trigger click on OutlineTextField. Any suggestion?

Comment: True soon will need that updated version of compose but for time being I need to continue using 1.0.0. Tried using `Box` but when i type something in OutlineTextField It is moving focus to DropDownMenu and after that I can not type to OutlineTextField until I select item from DropDown.  Any suggestion?

Comment: @ArpitPatel You can add a clickable Icon in the trailingIcon attribute : `trailingIcon = { Icon(icon,"contentDescription", modifier = Modifier.clickable { expanded = !expanded }) }`

Comment: Check also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67111020/exposed-drop-down-menu-for-jetpack-compose/67111599#67111599

Comment: Tried adding clickable param to modifier but getting same behaviour. I have added updated code to question for better understandability.