# Flutter Autofill email and password like netflix

Tags: flutter, autofill, password-manager

Can anyone please show me how can i implement password manager like netflix in flutter, Like if user clicking on email textfield then show stored email and password like netflix does.
Thank You.

Comment: See [this comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/57320#issuecomment-728162232) on GitHub for some relevant information.

Answer (score 7):

To enable autofill for username and password,

Follow these three steps:

1. Wrap your column of textfields and submit button with AutofillGroup().
   [image]
2. In your TextFields,
   set ***autofillHints:*** property as **[AutofillHints.username]** or **[AutofillHints.password]** as required.
   [image]
3. When user clicks on submit button call **TextInput.finishAutofillContext();**
   [image]

For detail explanation, [see here](https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/379/autofill-username-password/#step-1-enable-autofill-on-form).

Comment: Do you have sample code for Jetpack Compose

Comment: Maybe these links can help. [Medium Article](https://medium.com/@bagadeshrp/compose-ui-textfield-autofill-6e2ac434e380#:~:text=Jetpack%20Compose%20AutoFill&text=Compose%20Provides%20help%20in%20the,cancel%20based%20on%20our%20needs.&text=The%20documentation%20is%20non%2Dexistent,use%20the%20things%20you%20require.), [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64419367/does-jetpack-compose-offer-a-material-autocomplete-textview-replacement)

Comment: Thanks, even : https://bryanherbst.com/2021/04/13/compose-autofill/ It does not help me also

Comment: Does it allow to update new password into Google `autofill framework` after login success from android app? I does not have many info. about this.\

Answer (score 0):

You can pass autofillHints to textfield

```
 TextField1(
       autofillHints: [AutofillHints.email],
 ),
 TextField2(
       autofillHints: [AutofillHints.password],
 ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextEditingControl` to control the text.

Comment: hi, please could you edit your answer to explain in more detail? thank you in advance